# Intercept "command not found" error in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, trap

Is there a way to intercept the "command not found" error in ZSH? I've seen this is possible in bash apparently, but I couldn't find anything about doing it in zsh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is; it's the same as in bash, you make a function named `command_not_found_handler`. It'll be passed all the arguments that were given in the shell

```
$ foobar baz
zsh: command not found: foobar
$ function command_not_found_handler() {echo "You tried to run $1 with arg $2";}
$ foobar baz
You tried to run foobar with arg baz
```