# How to define a function that handles `command not found`?

Tags: zsh, error-handling, oh-my-zsh, command-not-found

I'd like to define a function that is called, whenever a shell-user types a command that does not exist. In my case I'd like to log the errors and try alternative commands.

currently, when typing e.g. `dgfgsdjagfghsdg` the error `zsh: command not found: dgfgsdjagfghsdg` is shown.

Is there a way to define a function, that get the typed command (+ arguments) as a parameter?

Comment: for example & for reference, here's a bash/zsh handler that prints out a random insult whenever the user types in a command that does not exist: https://github.com/hkbakke/bash-insulter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

- In the Z shell it is a function named [`command_not_found_handler`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#Command-Execution).
- In the Bourne Again shell it is a function named [`command_not_found_handle`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution).

## Further reading

- [Intercept "command not found" error in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/)
- [how to locally redefine 'command_not_found_handle'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74917/)
- [(2x) zsh: command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259897/)
- [No command 'bla' found, did you mean:?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279055/)

Answer (score 0):

To complement [JdeBP's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333259/41858), in the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/) it's called [`fish_command_not_found`](https://fishshell.com/docs/3.2/cmds/fish_command_not_found.html).